# ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer When DF gets too large?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame where i am calculating previous data points % change relative to the current data point for X units of `lookback`. I have been using this code from a while and it seems to work fine until i try to do a certain amount of lookback units.

```
for x in range(1, lookback + 1):
    df['_relhist_' + str(x)] = df['value'].shift(periods=x, fill_value=np.nan) / df['value'] - 1
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

The stacktrace says the error is thrown at the `dropna` line

There is columns of other dtypes, but the only column in use here is `value`, where is successfully downcast to a `np.float32` prior to creating the relative history.

```
df['value'] = df['value'].astype(np.float32)
```

The odd part is when i do let's say 1000 units of lookback, my samples are created without error and this code does what i expect it to do (drop rows that do not have enough prior rows). However, when i try to do 1500 units of lookback, this is where i get this error thrown.

Comment: You can provide the more detailed error trace, or an example that reproduces the problem? It seems odd that the `dropna` would attempt to do any sort of "conversion".